# Where can I get NY small businesses data, including revenue, number of employees etc?

Tags: data-request, usa, business

I'm helping a nonprofit reach small businesses in NY. Looking specifically for revenue, number of employees, type of business and ethnicity of the owner. Is there any place I can find such information?

Answer (score 3):

There is a [New York State Directory of Minority/Women-owned Business Enterprises](https://ny.newnycontracts.com/FrontEnd/VendorSearchPublic.asp?TN=ny&XID=4687). You can search using a form on that page, or download the entire directory as CSV or Excel.

It has the following columns:

1. Company Name
2. DBA Name
3. Owner First
4. Owner Last
5. Physical Address
6. City
7. State
8. Zip
9. Mailing Address
10. City
11. State
12. Zip
13. Phone
14. Fax
15. Email
16. Agency
17. Certification Type
18. Capability
19. Work Districts/Regions
20. Industry
21. Business Size
22. General Location
23. Location